# Why is my presigned URL for an Amazon S3 bucket expiring before the expiration time that I specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a piece of code that sends out a mail with a pre signed S3 URL which i generate in Java using AWS SDK(1.11.482) like this:

```
ZonedDateTime expiration = ZonedDateTime.now();
expiration = expiration.plusDays(7);
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =  new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(<Bucket>, <Key>).withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    .withExpiration(Date.from(expiration.toInstant()));

AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(<Region>)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(<AccessKey>, <SecretKey>))).build()

String s3Url = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();
```

However, instead of expiring in 7 days, it expires in approx 24 hours. Oddly enough, if i look at the actual url:

```
https://<AWS S3 Url>
?X-Amz-Security-Token=<Token>
&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Date=20190117T072701Z
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Expires=604799
&X-Amz-Credential=<Credential>aws4_request
&X-Amz-Signature=<Signature>
```

Then the expiry timestamp is actually what i would expect. But even when accessing it after 24 hour i get:

```
<Error>
<Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
<Token-0>
FQoGZXIvYXdzEPD//////////wEaDNkjQqZnq1LsP/9OCCKIAtq5Au7PKYSxzcqpwPlTF9DH3oyOrjo2Zft91L1pkCKX5VXHCFPClo0b0V5jo+GaNjHBLNYWN7lrUJm+20hOPURxvP/7ytZ5w5L3kk0DiisDdqPlup4xBUXGAOXqnQrjd7CqV6R0cr+8AD+tEh8QXZFxz//VCYKviFRA3vO/fIimuRq9Os4CACXLuuEU3GDKpDkhoHSN70tgmxMr2xBD6Wlo2UFClSUOt5pNzbSAjgD896fWSqf3C5DbZVAuasK/z2IOAI0OG6N/auOnsBBkLJ23nLvHrjzgnJZaKO/JSaG4PF0jyOphED8fvQ1V5P8xm2gDKT/shv1U1IQLYJjRVzZySdpStZMJfCiwxYDiBQ==
</Token-0>
<RequestId>23CFB9FB0973C599</RequestId>
<HostId>
G4tEmvGfauxHfkcyuGgTDJ+JxAJ4DEO6WPcDwBWkDBMLnw0R1cdTepUFHbIGmSF/FeV/oYnSq7c=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Note: Access and Secret Key are associated with IAM user with no expiry set.

Comment: Are you sure that you're signing with IAM credentials (just access key and secret key) and not STS credentials (access key, secret key, and session token)?

Comment: @jarmod I am using IAM User credentials(access key, secret key) with S3 full access

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a presigned URL that's valid for up to 7 days, first designate the IAM user credentials (the access key and secret access key) to the SDK that you're using (this seems to be the Java AWS SDK in your case). Then, generate a presigned URL using **AWS Signature Version 4**.

Here is an example with Boto in python:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

# Get the service client with sigv4 configured
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

Also, I know you mentionned it but you need to make sure you are using credentials directly from an IAM user and not from an IAM role since their token gets rotated every 24-36 hours.

Comment: This doesn't address the core of the issue here, which is that what has expired is the *token*, not the *signature*. `<Code>ExpiredToken</Code>`

Comment: I added more information about the necessary credentials to properly sign the url. @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @Jean-MichelProvencher Hi Jean-Michel, I don't believe that the issue is related to the signature version. Though it's hard to find definitive documentation here, I believe that v2 pre-signed URLs have a much longer max expiry time (end of Unix time?) than v4 URLs. So going to v4 actually reduces the expiration time, not increases it.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it's related to the credentials used to sign the url. According to up-to-date S3 documentation, the ExpiredToken is caused by using STS or instance role credentials that only support expiry time up to 36 hours.

Comment: @Jean-MichelProvencher Although i have written code to explicitly pass the IAM user credentials(access and secret key), somehow its still using STS,

Comment: @Yogesh how are you currently passing credentials? see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.htm for different way of passing credentials that may solve your problem.

Comment: @Yogesh immediately before the call to generate the presigned URL, retrieve and print out the AWSCredentials associated with the S3 client object that you've created. Also, any chance that the code you have shown us, that uses BasicAWSCredentials, is not actually what you are running?